# updating a row in a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Is it better to use INSERT, REPLACE or ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, to update a row in my database?

I'm currently using:

```
mysql_query("insert into pages (pages_id, pagename, pagedesc, pagekey, pagecont) values('$pages_id', $pagename', '$pagedesc', '$pagekey', '$pagecont')");
```

to create new rows in the DB.

pages_id is an auto_increment field in the mysql database. I'm not sure which is the best way to update an existing row in the database?

Comment: Why not just use `update table set field=value where id=key`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are updating an existing row (and you're 100% sure it exists), definitely go for UPDATE.

BUT

If you are "updating" a row which may not exist, go for "INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE".

Answer (score 3):

Ironically, you use [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/update.html) to update a row in SQL.

```
UPDATE pages SET ... WHERE pages_id = $pages_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UPDATE` and specify the pages_id?

Here's a tutorial on `UPDATE`: [UPDATE tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)

Little example:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET pagename = $pagename WHERE pages_id = $page_id");
```

On a completely different note though, stop using mysql* functions and start working with PDO, it's a lot safer!

Comment: Thanks for your help @Bono !
Can I set all of the variables with one SET, like this: mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET pagename = $pagename, pagedesc = $pagedesc, pagekey = $pagekey, pagecont = $pagecont, WHERE pages_id = $pages_id");

Also what is PDO??

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` is always a heavier operation than `UPDATE`. `INSERT` has to allocate memory for the newly inserted item, while `UPDATE` performs search on the table and doesn't have look for new memory. This difference becomes critical when you have to insert many records in a short period of time. Better to `INSERT` when DB is not very busy and then `UPDATE` when necessary.